# How can I switch the language in which websites are displayed in Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, language

I would like all websites that I visit in my Chrome browser to be displayed in English.

This example of [Sunrise Calendar in the Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sunrise-calendar/mojepfklcankkmikonjlnidiooanmpbb), for instance, is being displayed in German.

How can I set that all websites by default use English?

[image]

**Figure 1: Example website that is shown in German instead of English**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### I would like all websites that I visit in my Chrome browser to be displayed in English.

Note:

- Not all websites provide an English language version.

> When your browser pulls a document from the Web, it sends a request to the server where the information is stored. This is known as an HTTP request. With the request, the browser sends information about its language preference settings.
>
> The HTTP request carries this language preference information in the Accept-Language header. If the server is set up to return alternate versions of a page or resource in more than one language, and the language you prefer is available, it will go through a process known as HTTP content negotiation to find content in the language(s) indicated in the HTTP request. If there is only one version of a page on the server, that version will be retrieved. If none of the languages you request are available, the server should be set up to return a default language choice.

...

> **Chrome**.
>
> 1. Open the browser settings.
>
>    [image]
> 2. Click "Show advanced settings..."
> 3. In the advanced section scroll down to find "Languages".
>
>    [image]
> 4. Click "Language and Input Settings"
>
>    [image]
> 5. Click "Add" and select the language or language+region choice you want from the list available.
> 6. Order the resulting list (drag and drop) so that it is in descending order of preference.
>
>    [image]
> 7. You don't need to restart Chrome.
>
> Notes:
>
> - If you choose a language+region combination, Chrome will set that
>     option followed by just the vanilla language. For example, if you
>     choose French (Canada), Chrome will add that followed by French in
>     your on-screen preference list.
> - If you then add French (Switzerland), it will add that choice to the
>     bottom of your list and you will need to manually move the French
>     (Switzerland) choice before the vanilla French choice in the dialog
>     box.
> - You can't create custom language tags.

Source [Setting language preferences in a browser](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities)

Answer (score 3):

Open the `settings` menu from the grill in the top-right corner.

Click `Show advanced settings...` at the bottom of the page.

Under the `Languages` header, click the `Language and input settigns...` button.

Add languages and drag to order them based on your preference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tip for those who (like me) experience this problem and try to fix it using similar advice found all over the Internet.
Yes, these suggestions should work, but most times they won't because the core problem when the Chrome browser misbehaves like this is the old cookies from the website, saved on your computer.
Even before taking the above actions (which, by the way, are somewhat useless because Chrome should already have them since when you installed it), just go to Settings, find "Cookies and other site data", scroll down to "All cookies and site data" and search for the respective domain/website and delete all cookies.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1109087)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the language settings in Chrome settings did not work for me.  It was the headers that remained in German even if the main result was in English
I went into my Account settings and the language said that it was in English but there was a noted that flagged up that some applications were not in English (or words to that effect) and gave an option to change all applications to English which I did and it worked.
I had also reset to original state (it took a while to run) in Settings, Advanced settings, and that worked for a while then it reverted (why I do not know)