# Chrome: Switch language in which websites are displayed with website-specific language choice

Tags: google-chrome

I want most of the websites I visit to be displayed in English.

However, some websites I would prefer to be shown in another language. Currently, since my default language in Chrome is English, all websites are shown in English and I have to manually switch when visiting those I would like to see in another language.

I.e., I would like to set something like 'default language exceptions' or website-specific language configurations.

I am aware of [How can I switch the language in which websites are displayed in Chrome browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/1066152/how-can-i-switch-the-language-in-which-websites-are-displayed-in-chrome-browser), but that shows only how to set the default language for *all* websites, not how to set exceptions for specific websites.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/language?hl=en-GB&_category=extensions

Comment: @spikey_richie those are all translation programs. I do not need to translate, the websites I am talking about have versions in different languages and I want to configure chrome to choose a specific among them. But I do not want to change Chrome's default language setting, since on other websites I still want English.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you have found a way to make a one-off change for a particular website (I am assuming not, but I'd find such a thing useful).

Comment: no, unfortunately I was not successful yet, but am still interested in a solution