# Stop sites from automatically changing language

Tags: browser, internet, language, website, regional-settings

I live in Belgium, which has two *(3)* official languages, this causes sites to act funky.
I am Dutch speaking, and prefer to read in English.

However, because of my region and because of French being much more prevalent, when I go to e.g. Microsoft and I type in microsoft.com it automatically gets turned into *https://www.microsoft.com/fr-be/*.

I know I can change the language in the site itself however some sites suck, and it gets annoying to do this every single time.

This is why I was wondering if anyone knows a solution to this, I know about a VPN. But this would really be last resort because of money and speed.

I have already tried [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1066152/how-can-i-switch-the-language-in-which-websites-are-displayed-in-chrome-browser) to no avail.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: I use edge chromium, I have tried chrome , same thing. I could try firefox?

Comment: If both of them are giving same result, I suppose trying firefox won't fetch you the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have got an effective work-around for this. You can't stop the language-specific redirect in those websites but can choose to read everything in English and not French. This can be achieved in Chrome, however, I haven't tried in other browsers yet.

Go To `Menu>Settings>Languages` in Chrome, and do the following:

[image]

After that, Click on the option that says "Offer to translate pages in this language" like this:

[image]

*(here the options are greyed out; it won't be so in your case)*

Now, Relaunch the browser. So, next time whenever you visit a page which has language other than English, you will see an option to translate the whole page to English in just one click::

[image]

And there you go. So, this is the best that I could find that will work for you. Hope this helps.

Or, if you don't like doing all this and still want to read in English, just install this Google Translate extension. Here is the link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?hl=en

Comment: This answer isn't wrong, but I'd like to add that, for whatever Chrome does right, it doesn't allow you to seperately manage region settings (like date notation). This means that changing the language can mess up dates, times and other regional settings, like turning 24h notation into AM and PM, or d-m-y to m/d/y